# System.InvalidOperationException: session is not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome versione 97 using VisualStudio Selenium C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to run selected tests on Visual Studio (Selenium C#) and getting error message:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: session is not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome versione 97. Current Browser version is 100.0.4896.88
```

TearDown:

```
SystemNullReferenceException: Onject reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

The Problem is in other solution created by myself (above one is from the team project) everything is running fine and no error message appeared.

Tried latest update of ChromeDriver on NUGet package installed. And just in case requested Chrome Browser version 97

What can be the issue if in one solution it is working in another I have this error message?

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
System.InvalidOperationException: session is not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome versione 97. Current Browser version is 100.0.4896.88
```

...implies that the [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59927747/7429447) was unable to initiate/spawn a new *Browsing Context* i.e. [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) session.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- You are using *chromedriver=97.0*
- Release Notes of [*ChromeDriver v97.0*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/97.0.4692.71/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports Chrome version 97

- But you are using *chrome=100.0.4896.88*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=100.0*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/100.0.4896.60/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports Chrome version 100

So there is a clear mismatch between *chromedriver=97.0* and the *chrome=100.0.4896.88*

---

### Solution

Ensure that:

- *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v100.0](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=100.0.4896.60/) level.
- *Chrome Browser* is updated to  current *chrome=100.0* (as per [chromedriver=100.0.4896.60 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/100.0.4896.60/notes.txt)).

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I understand mismatch here, but in NuGet Packager manager Selenium.Webdriver.ChromeDriver is up to date and installed version is latest stable 100.0.4896.6000, but after run it says it supports only Chrome version 97. So that’s why litlle bit confused:(

Comment: Not a NuGet package expert. But from Selenium perspective I have explained the issue and suggested the solution.